A question about a proof of positive semidefiniteness of a block matrix
$M,N$ are $m\times n$ complex matrices.
My question is about proof by @orzweb111 of the following inequality,
$$1-\sqrt{\det\left(I+MM^H\right)-1}\cdot\sqrt{\det\left(I+NN^H\right)-1}\leqslant\left|\det\left(I+MN^H\right)\right|\tag1$$
pasted below:

Proof. Clearly $$\begin{pmatrix} I+MM^H & I+MN^H\\ I+NM^H &I+NN^H\end{pmatrix}\ge \begin{pmatrix} I & I\\ I & I\end{pmatrix},$$
where $A\ge B$ means $A-B$ is positive semidefinite.
This gives $$\begin{pmatrix} \det(I+MM^H) & \det(I+MN^H)\\\det(I+NM^H) & \det(I+NN^H)\end{pmatrix}\ge \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix},$$ in other words, the matrix$ \begin{pmatrix}\det(I+MM^H)-1 & \det(I+MN^H)-1\\ \det(I+NM^H)-1 &\det(I+NN^H)-1\end{pmatrix}$ is positive semidefinite. Taking determinant gives the desired result.

I don't understand the step "This gives $\scriptsize\begin{pmatrix} \det(I+MM^H) & \det(I+MN^H)\\\det(I+NM^H) & \det(I+NN^H)\end{pmatrix}\ge \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix}$".
I guess he is using some well-known fact (The mapping from a block matrix to the matrix of its determinants preserves Loewner order $A\ge B$)?
I can't reach the author for help since the forum where the proof was posted is inactive.
The closest thing I could find is Wikipedia "Definite matrix" entry "Block matrices and submatrices" section but it doesn't seem to be relevant.

Related facts:

$\det(I+MM^H)\geq 1$ Here is a proof
$\det(I+MN^H) = \overline{\det(I+NM^H)}$
Proof:
$\det(I+MN^H) = \det((I+NM^H)^H)=\overline{\det(I+NM^H)}$


Positive semidefiniteness of a block matrix of positive semidefinite matrices


The mapping from a block matrix to the matrix of its determinants seems to be known as a "partial determinant" as introduced by Choi 2017. There are in fact two such ways to take such a partial determinant, with the one used here appearing to be the simpler $\det_2$ case. There are some nice inequalities for this mapping; in particular, one has $\det_2(A+B)\geq \det_2 A+\det_2 B$ if $A,B\geq 0$ (again using $\geq$ as Loewner order). That seems quite close to what you want but not identical.

From @Semiclassical's comment,$\def\succeq{\mathbin{\text{≽}}}$

$\det_2(A+B)\succeq \det_2 A+\det_2 B$ if $A,B\succeq 0$

we have$$
\begin{pmatrix} \det(I+MM^H) & \det(I+MN^H)\\\det(I+NM^H) & \det(I+NN^H)\end{pmatrix}\succeq\begin{pmatrix}\det I&\det I\\\det I&\det I\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}\det(MM^H)&\det(MN^H)\\\det(NM^H)&\det(NN^H)\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now$$\begin{pmatrix}\det I&\det I\\\det I&\det I\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
and $$\begin{pmatrix}\det(MM^H)&\det(MN^H)\\\det(NM^H)&\det(NN^H)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}|\det M|^2&\det M\overline{\det N}\\\det N\overline{\det M}&|\det N|^2\end{pmatrix}\succeq0$$
so
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \det(I+MM^H)-1 & \det(I+MN^H)-1\\\det(I+NM^H)-1 & \det(I+NN^H)-1\end{pmatrix}\succeq0
$$
so
$$(\det(I+MM^H)-1)(\det(I+NN^H)-1)\geqslant|\det(I+MN^H)-1|^2$$
Taking square roots
$$\sqrt{\det(I+MM^H)-1}\sqrt{\det(I+NN^H)-1}\geqslant|\det(I+MN^H)-1|$$
Apply triangle inequality $|1-z|+|z|\geqslant1$ to $z=\det(1+MN^H)\in\mathbb{C}$ we get $|\det(I+MN^H)-1|\geqslant1-|\det(I+MN^H)|$, so $(1)$ is proved.

While this proof works if $m=n$, in general the matrices $M,N$ will be rectangular and thus $\det(MN^H)=\det(M)\overline{\det{N}}$ does not hold. (Indeed, the RHS is not in general meaningful even though the LHS is.) So a different argument seems required for establishing $\det_2 B\succeq 0$.

@Semiclassical Yes. Maybe use Cauchy–Binet formula to patch the proof? I'm not sure.

Perhaps, though I fear that will just make things more complicated.

if $m\gt n$ you can just append columns of zeros to each of $M$ and $N$; this does not change $I + MM^$ or $I+MN^$ etc.  If $m\lt n$ I would probably try instead to work with $M^*M$, $N^*M$, $M^N$ and $N^N$ and then re-use the prior sentence's argument (i.e. appending columns of zeros to $M^$ and $N^$).
