$\det(AA^H+I)\geqslant\det(A\overline{A}+I)$ for $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$
Let $A$ be a complex $n\times n$ matrix, is it true that $\det(AA^H+I)\geqslant\det(A\overline{A}+I)$? where $A^H$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$ and $\overline{A}$ is the element-wise conjugate of $A$.
I tried examples:
$n=1$: It is trivial (equal).
$n=2$: Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a_1+ia_2&a_3+ia_4\\a_5+ia_6&a_7+ia_8\end{pmatrix}$, then $\det(AA^H+I)-\det(A\overline{A}+I)=(a_3-a_5)^2+(a_4-a_6)^2$.

I'm not following why you asked this.  In your thread yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5003378/a-question-about-a-proof-of-positive-semidefiniteness-of-a-block-matrix/ , which you answered before asking this question, you deduced $\begin{pmatrix} \det(I+MM^H)-1 & \det(I+MN^H)-1\\det(I+NM^H)-1 & \det(I+NN^H)-1\end{pmatrix}\succeq \mathbf 0$   $\iff B=\begin{pmatrix} \det(I+MM^H) & \det(I+MN^H)\\det(I+NM^H) & \det(I+NN^H)\end{pmatrix}\succeq \mathbf {11}^T \succeq \mathbf 0$ so set $M:=A$ and $N:=A^T$. Then $\det\big(B\big)\geq 0$ answers this question.

Yes, it is true. First, note that when $U,V$ are two unitary matrices, $S$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix, we have
\begin{align*}
|\det(USVS+I)|
&=\left|\det\left(\pmatrix{US&I}\pmatrix{VS\\ I}\right)\right|\\
&=\left|\sum_{K\in\binom{[2n]}{n}}\det\pmatrix{US&I}_{[n],K}\,\det\pmatrix{VS\\ I}_{K,[n]}\right|\quad\text{(Cauchy-Binet formula)}\\
&\le\sum_{K\in\binom{[2n]}{n}}\left|\det\pmatrix{US&I}_{[n],K}\,\det\pmatrix{VS\\ I}_{K,[n]}\right|.\\
\end{align*}
Note that in the previous line, $\pmatrix{US&I}_{[n],K}=\pmatrix{(US)_{[n],J_1}&(I)_{[n],J_2}}$ for some index sets $J_1,J_2\subseteq[n]$ such that $|J_1|+|J_2|=n$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
|\det\pmatrix{US&I}_{[n],K}|
&=|\det\pmatrix{(US)_{[n],\,J_1}&I_{[n],\,J_2}}|\\
&=|\det(US)_{[n]\setminus J_2,\,J_1}|\\
&\le|\det(S)_{[n]\setminus J_2,\,J_1}| \quad\text{(Hadamard determinant inequality)}\\
&=|\det\pmatrix{S_{[n],\,J_1}&I_{[n],\,J_2}}|\\
&=|\det\pmatrix{S&I}_{[n],\,K}|
\end{align*}
and similarly,
\begin{align*}
\left|\det\pmatrix{VS\\ I}_{K,[n]}\right|
\le\left|\det\pmatrix{S\\ I}_{K,[n]}\right|.
\end{align*}
It follows that
\begin{align*}
|\det(USVS+I)|
&\le\sum_{K\in\binom{[2n]}{n}}\left|\det\pmatrix{S&I}_{[n],K}\,\det\pmatrix{S\\ I}_{K,[n]}\right|\\
&=\sum_{K\in\binom{[2n]}{n}}\det\pmatrix{S&I}_{[n],K}\,\det\pmatrix{S\\ I}_{K,[n]}\\
&=\det(S^2+I).
\end{align*}
Next, let $U_1SV_1^H$ be a singular value decomposition of $A$. Then
\begin{align*}
\det(A\overline{A}+I)
&=\det(U_1SV_1^H\overline{U_1SV_1^H}+I)\\
&=\det\left(U_1SV_1^H\overline{U_1}SV_1^T+I\right)\\
&=\det\left((V_1^TU_1)S(V_1^H\overline{U_1})S+I\right)\\
&\le\det(S^2+I)\\
&=\det(AA^H+I).
\end{align*}
Remark. $\det(A\overline{A}+I)$ is always real because $\det(A\overline{A}+I)=\det(\overline{A}A+I)=\overline{\det(A\overline{A}+I)}$. It can actually be shown that the determinant is nonnegative. See $\det(I+A\bar{A}) \ge 0$ for all complex square matrices $A$? .

Nice answer! Just one quip. Is it obvious that $\det(A\bar A+I)$ is real? (This follows from the fact that $A$ is consimilar to $\bar A$, but I was wondering if there’s a more straightforward way to see this.) Otherwise the inequality in the last bunch of equations doesn’t make sense.

@Pranay It is real because $\det(I+A\overline{A})=\det(I+\overline{A}A)=\overline{\det(I+A\overline{A})}$. I think it has been proven on this site that the determinant is actually nonnegative, but I cannot find the link.

Sorry, I don’t see why the first equality is obvious. Isn’t that what you have to prove?

@Pranay The first equality follows from Sylvester’s secular theorem, which says that $\det(xI-AB)=\det(xI-BA)$ for all square matrices $A$ and $B$. It is not what the OP wants to prove. $\overline{A}$ is the complex conjugate of $A$, not the conjugate transpose of $A$.

Ah got it thanks!
